# ARKit Plane detection

Tags: xcode9-beta, arkit, swift4

I am trying to use the code provided by the apple in Demo ARKit app for plane detection, but it's not working consistently, for some cases it detects the surface perfectly but in some cases, it does not detects the plane. Then, I also noticed in the Demo ARKit app same thing happens with plane detection. 
When it detects plane surface the yellow square closes but that is not the case every time. Has any one faced the same? How to make this plane detection behavior consistent?

Answer (score 10):

Plane detection depends a lot on real world conditions. You need good lighting, a surface that has a decent amount of visible detail, and a decent amount of clear flat space. For example, a plain white table or a black tablecloth makes plane detection much slower / less reliable. A wood desk with visible grain works much better, but not if it's cluttered with keyboards and mice and cables and devices (not that any of us would have a desk like that, of course...).

Plane detection involves motion and parallax triangulation, too. If you point your device at a good surface (as described above), but only change your perspective on that surface by rotating the device (say, by spinning in your swivel chair), you're not feeding ARKit much more useful information than if you just held still. On the other hand, if you move the device side to side or up and down by at least several inches, its perspective on the surface will gain some parallax, which will speed/improve plane detection.

---

*Update:* If you're developing an app that depends on plane detection, it helps to cue the user to perform these motions. The third party demos they showed in the labs at WWDC17 had some great app-specific ways to do this: Lego had a little mini game of guiding a toy helicopter in to a landing, *The Walking Dead* tells the player to search the floor for zombie footprints; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add more light in room. ArKit works better in well lighted room.
You can't affect on plane detection. Wait for official iOS 11 release.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
     self.sceneView.debugOptions = [SCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints, SCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]
     self.configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
     self.sceneView.session.run(configuration)
     self.sceneView.delegate = self
     super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
//MARK: - ARSEN delegate -
  extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
      func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeDetection = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else {
        return
    }
    print("Plane anchor detect")
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let planeDetecttion = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else {
        return
    }
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRemove node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard anchor is ARPlaneAnchor else{
        return
    }
 }
}
```